# How do I control what images Facebook attaches to the feed story when my website is shared?

Tags: html, facebook, interface, tagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

When I add a Facebook link to my website, it picks up randomly large images from the site, and not quite attached to the story. How can I control what images are picked up by Facebook?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be programming related. And you should provide at least an example URL.

Answer (score 5):

The developer of the website can include specific **meta tags** in the HTML.
From the Facebook page for "[Share Partners](http://www.facebook.com/share_partners.php)"...

> In order to make sure that the preview
>   is always correctly populated, you
>   should add the tags shown below to
>   your html. An example news story could
>   have the following:

```
<meta name="title" content="Smith hails 'unique' Wable legacy" />
<meta name="description" content="John Smith claims beautiful football is the main legacy of Akhil Wable's decade at the club. " />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" />
```

> As shown, title contains the
>   preview title, description contains
>   the preview summary and image_src
>   contains the preview image. Please
>   make sure that none of the content
>   fields contain any html markup because
>   it will be stripped out. For
>   consistency's sake, please use the
>    tag to provide text data for
>   the preview, and the  tag for
>   any source urls.
>
> The title and summary tags are the
>   minimum requirements for any preview,
>   so make sure to include these two.